# как не нарушить авторские права в google play (картинкой)?

Tags: android, google-play

Написал тематическое приложение на телефон,уже все готово и апк файл собран,но стал много читать статей "за что банят разработчиков" + [документацию](https://play.google.com/intl/ru/about/developer-content-policy-print/).

Меня смутил пункт "Нарушение прав на товарный знак".Я использую картинку для фона в приложении [image: введите сюда описание изображения](обрезал ее немного) и не знаю можно ли это делать. **Как понять могут ли за это забанить?** 
Сама картинка взята с фонового [видео](http://www.dota2.com/international/battlepass) на сайте

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы сказал здесь речь про графические объекты.

Цитата из правил

> Если у вас есть письменное разрешение от правообладателя, то
>   интеллектуальную собственность (бренд, логотип и графические объекты)
>   можно использовать в приложении или на его странице. Обязательно
>   свяжитесь с командой Google Play перед публикацией приложения, чтобы
>   его не отклонили за нарушение авторских прав.

Тк у вас нет разрешения от правообладателя графических объектов вас могут заблокировать если заподозрят нарушение.

Answer (score 0):

Это лого принадлежит Valve, как и любые другие созданные сотрудниками компании изображения, не имеешь права использовать ни торговый знак по отдельности, ни какое угодно другое сверстанное в Valve изображение (даже если на нем нет лого)